# Promises when executed differently displaying different results

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

Just for the purpose of experimenting after diving into node quite recently, i wrote a simple promise code and then executed it from the command line. I saw two kind of outputs. Here's my code:

```
function doWork(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('done!');
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Then :

```
   1. doWork().then(function(){
        return doWork();
    }).then(function(){
        console.log('that\'s it');
    });

Output :

 done!
 done!
 that's it!
```

Another way:

```
2. doWork().then(function(){
            doWork();
        }).then(function(){
            console.log('that\'s it');
        });

Output: 

done!
that's it!
done!
```

Why does the output change when I don't `return` or when I do `return`?

Comment: return keeps the chain, without you start a new unconnected chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises work by return values. When you don't `return` the chain does not know to wait for the second `doWork` before continuing to the next handler in the chain.

Comment: my question is, if it breaks the chain, then why is it going back once again after printing `that's it`? Because the chain has already been broken?

Comment: The call to `doWork()` doesn't disappear into oblivion, it's still there but the "that's it" `then()` (you should name your functions, better for explanations) doesn't wait for it to finish. The code doesn't go back, it's how async works with javascript.

Comment: @nickB it's just a function call - function calls get executed and log - functions that return promises get called - but it only knows to "wait" by return value.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you break the promise chain by not returning it from then success handler.

```
doWork().then(function () {
    // this will be executed only after first call to doWork is resolved.
    // When this executes it returns the promise returned by doWork thereby asking next then handler to wait till this promise is resolved.
    return doWork();
}).then(function () {
    // since we are returning doWork second call promise, this will be executed only after it is resolved.
    // if we don't return doWork second call promise, it won't wait for promise to be resolved and directly execute.
    console.log('that\'s it');
});
```